# Understanding the concept of super?

Tags: java, inheritance, overriding

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around the concept of `super()`. Java Tutorials gives this example:

```
public class Superclass {
    public void printMethod() {
        System.out.println("Printed in Superclass.");
    }
}

public class Subclass extends Superclass {
    // overrides printMethod in Superclass
    public void printMethod() {
        super.printMethod();
        System.out.println("Printed in Subclass");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Subclass s = new Subclass();
        s.printMethod();    
    }
}
```

But if I am overriding the `printMethod`, why do I need to invoke the Superclass method? Why can't I just write whatever in the Subclass method of `printMethod()` and just move on?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java - using the 'super' keyword](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6879892/java-using-the-super-keyword)

Answer (score 3):

There is absolutely no need to call the super.
It just helps you to call the logic contained within super class method if you require that.
Many times you want the exact logic to run and then provide your additional logic.

Overriding always does not mean providing brand new logic. Sometimes you want to provide a slight variation. For e.g., if the method returns a value, then you call the super class method and get the value. Then you make some slight modification in that object using logic in the sub class method and return it back to caller.

Answer (score 0):

You can override it. In that case, the parent method is ignored. `super()` is used if you want the parent method to be executed in the subclass.

Answer (score 0):

This is used to avoid duplicated code. Let's say you have a class:

```
public class SuperClass() {
    private int var1;
    private int var2;
    private int var3;

    public SuperClass() {
        var1 = 1;
        var2 = 2;
        var3 = 3;   
    }
}
```

and a subclass:

```
public class SubClass() {
    private int var1;
    private int var2;
    private int var3;
    private int var4;

    public SubClass() {
        super();
        var4 = 4;
    }
}
```

In this example, you are using `super()` to invoke superclass constructor (constructor are usually used to initialize members) so you can focus on the `SubClass` members, and you don't have to repeat all the initialization lines (for `var1`, `var2` and `var3`).

Answer (score 0):

Basically the super class is the upper most level of the program. When you create a new subclass you must "inherit" from the super class using the keyword 'extends'. This does 2 things; It allows you to use any methods created in the super class, in the subclass and it also allows you overwrite methods in the super class. Basically, if you have one method you want to use in a bunch of classes you use the super class to create it and then the sub-classes can just call the method using standard dot notation.

Answer (score 0):

If you just run this program, Inside PrintMethod of the subclass will call to super class "printMethod" (print "Printed in Superclass") and then execute the things you have written in the sub class method(print "Printed in Subclass").

```
      public void printMethod() {
      //super.printMethod();   // comment this line
      System.out.println("Printed in Subclass");
     }
```

if you run like this, it will print only the things that you have written in the sub class method.

Idea is, If you want use Super class method information in the sub class, then you can call like Super.MethodName().

Answer (score 0):

**Clear Explanation :**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Subclass s = new Subclass();
    s.printMethod();    
 }
```

1. Subclass s = new Subclass();

   (i) when we are creating sub class object what wiill happens?
      constructor of subclss will be executed
     (ii) Do we have any costructor in sub class (Subclass )
        if we have dat will execute..
        but we are not having so default costructor will excecute
     (iii) what default costructor will have?

   Subclass (){
          super();
         }
     (iv) what super() will do?
        it calls super class contructor

   in super class also we are not having constructor so
     will execute default constructor

   Superclass(){
     super();

   ```
    }
   ```

   super class of **superclass** is Object class

   so Object class is the super class of evry class in java

   so it will creates object of object class..

   ```
       object of Object class created
                    |
   ```

   and comes to its subclass constructor...//step (iv)

   Superclass(){
     super(); // executed

   ```
    }

      object of Object class created
                    |
       object of Superclass  craeted
   ```

   so super class constuctror execution also completed so
   it will creates Object of SuperClass..

   then control comes to its subclass conctructor // step (iii)

   so   Subclass (){
          super(); // executed
         }

   after completion of subclass constructor it creates the object of  subclass

   ```
    *Important point : after completion of constructor execution 
            Object of thet class will be created*

        object of Object class created
                    |
       object of Superclass  craeted
                    |
         object of Subclass  craeted
   ```

   all this happened because of  Subclass s = new **Subclass();**

   1. so when you created object of sub class 3 objects are created..
   2. s.printMethod();

      ```
      now you are calling a method on subclass object


                                       ^
      ```
   3. printMethod() is there in super class and sub class

      when u r calling a method on sub class object what happens?

      (i) it will search for that method in outer most objest: Object of Object class
        so now printMethod() is not there in object of object class
      (ii) Next its searches in next superclass object ie. object of Superclass 
        object Superclass  object having printMethod() method

      (iii) so method found...eventhougth method found controll serches in next sub most object is object of subclass object....

      (iv) two methos found in two object but it excecutes sub most object method.

      so sub most object is Subclass object...

      so it executes the subclass printMethod() method.

**Note: when we call a method on object it will executes the sub most objects method if ovverriden.....**

now our method is....

```
public void printMethod() {
    super.printMethod();
    System.out.println("Printed in Subclass");
}
```

first line in this method is  super.printMethod();

by default super ponts to super class object : object of Superclass

object of Superclass  .printMethod() is

public void printMethod() {
        System.out.println("Printed in Superclass.");
    }

so prints :

**Printed in Superclass.**

next line is :   System.out.println("Printed in Subclass");

**so it prints : Printed in Subclass**

Note : first while creating object it called super class constructor..

now in method called super class method..

Note:

1.if class not having any constructor jvm assigns default constructor as

ClassName(){
 super(); calls super class constructor
}

1. if class alrdy having constructor

   the first line of the constructor should be the super() call.

for example:  class A{
                 int variablea;

```
             A(int a){

            variablea=a;

              }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
       A a=new A(2);   
            }

           }


    in this example 
     A(int a){

            variablea=a;

              }   code replaces with


           A(int a){
           super(); by jvm by default

            variablea=a;

              }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `super` in a subclass to refer to its immediate superclass. Super has two general forms.

1. to call the super class's constructor from the subclass
2. to access a member of the superclass from the subclass

I'm assuming that you are trying to understand the second one.

An example which might make you understand how super helps in referencing members of the super class:

```
public class Human {
String name;
int age;
public void printDetails() {
  System.out.println("Name:"+name);
  System.out.println("Age:"+age);
}
}

public class Student extends Human {
int rollNumber;
String grade;
public void printDetails() {
    super.printDetails();
    System.out.println("Roll Number:"+rollNumber);
    System.out.println("Grade:"+grade);
}   

public void printNameAgeAndSayGoodMorning(){
    super.printDetails();
    System.out.println("Good morning!");
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Student s = new Student();
    s.name="MyName";
    s.age=27;
    s.rollNumber=3;
    s.grade="A+";
    s.printDetails(); 
    System.out.println(); //just an empty line
    s.printNameAgeAndSayGoodMorning();      
}

}
```

I avoided constructors or any getter/setter methods for simplicity.

In this example, do you think you really have to "just write whatever in the Subclass" instead of reusing the `printDetails()` method available in the super class?